# Switching User Contexts in Visual Studio and TFS Source Control

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, windows-7, virtual-machine, reverse-proxy

While developing ASP.net applications on a Windows 7 machine in Visual Studio. Sometimes I need to do testing for Internet Explorer 6 compatibility. The way I test IE 6 is I have virtual machine running on my local machine.

The easiest way I could figure out to access development on my parent development machine was to switch my ASP.net project to use my machine's local IIS and then access it via the virtual machines. One problems with this is that in order to switch to project to use the machine's local IIS is to run Visual Studio as Administrator.

While I'm running as Administrator and perform a "Get Latest" on TFS Source Control I run into permission's issues the next time I'm running Visual Studio in a non-elevated security context. Firstly, the rights aren't there for Visual Studio to overwrite the files. I originally thought that this was an ownership issue. I went to my Worspace directory and did a recursive change owner on that folder but that didn't seem to solve the problem. The only definite way to overcome this issue is to either keep running Visual Studio in the elevated context, or delete everything in my workspace and get a fresh copy.

I'd prefer not to ever have to switch Visual Studio to run at an elevated security context, but since the IDE's development server cannot be accessed remotely I'm feel like this isn't an option. I've found that it's possible to setup a reverse proxy so that it can be accessed but the only tool I found to do this with is quite expensive and I couldn't find any instructions I could understand on setting up a reverse proxy with a free tool.

If anyone could provide instructions on how to setup a reverse proxy with some tool that is freely available for Win7 that would be nominal, otherwise I would like to hear suggestions on resolving the permissions issues. Deleting a project and getting fresh works but it consumes a fair amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you could use Fiddler; [Here is a post](http://encosia.com/2010/06/10/using-an-iphone-with-the-visual-studio-development-server/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+Encosia+(Encosia)) with instructions on using Fiddler to allow an iphone to work with the dev web server, I imagine you could tweak for your situation.

Alternatively, maybe [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) would work for you?

Comment: Quickly reading the other article, it mentions that IIS Express integrates with 2010, however I've not been allowed to upgrade the project to 2010 ala the management. I will look more closely at this option though to see if 2008 will work.

Comment: I haven't actually used IIS Express, but my understanding was that it could be installed and configured to serve any folder on your HDD; The VS 2010 integration just simplifies things.

Comment: awesome, the iphone article does what I need, instead of a reverse proxy, this is just a regular proxy that you connect the virtual pc to. Thanks!